# JQueryUI autocomplete: раскрыть список вверх

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Использую `Autocomplete` у `jQueryUI`. Как сделать, чтобы раскрывался список вверх?

Вот код для тестирования, взят с примера: http://jsfiddle.net/9xu9Z/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно сам разобрался :) http://jsfiddle.net/9xu9Z/1/

При создании элемента добавил свойство:

```
            position: {
                my: "left bottom",
                at: "left top",
                of: input,
                collision: "flip flip"
            },
```